# Calculate working Hours in given shift time

Tags: python, datetime, hash-map

This is simple program to calculate working hours in given shift..
It is also return user sessions and presence of user shift.

while this works fine. I would like suggestion to improve it.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
user_attendence = [{"id": 1, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 02:10:00"},
                   {"id": 1, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 03:00:00"},

                   {"id": 1, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 04:00:00"},
                   {"id": 1, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 05:00:00"},

                   {"id": 1, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 06:00:00"},
                   {"id": 1, "punch": 0, "date": "22-04-2022 08:00:10"},

                   {"id": 2, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 04:00:00"},
                   {"id": 2, "punch": 1, "date": "22-04-2022 05:00:00"},

                   ]
time_format = '%H:%M:%S'
shift = ["22-04-2022 02:00:00", "22-04-2022 09:00:00"]


def getDays(obj):
    return (datetime.strptime(obj[1], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') - datetime.strptime(obj[0], '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')).days


def set_timeformat(self, formatstr=time_format):
    self.time_format = formatstr


def converTime(obj):
    return str(datetime.strptime(obj, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S').time())


def calculate(shift1, user_attendence, indate, id):
    """"
        timeList -> 02:00 AM, 08:00:AM
        date -> 22-04-2022
    """
    man_in = False
    man_out = False
    sessions = []
    is_present = False
    total_hours = datetime.strptime("00:00:00", '%H:%M:%S')
    in_time = "null"

    attendance = [i for i in user_attendence if shift1[0] <= i["date"] <= shift1[1] and i.get("id").__eq__(id)]
    if [i for i in attendance if i.get("punch").__eq__(1)]:
        is_present = True

    if is_present:
        for k in attendance:
            if k["punch"].__eq__(1):
                if not man_in:
                    in_time = converTime(k["date"])
                    man_in = True
                    man_out = False
                else:
                    dif = datetime.strptime(converTime(k["date"]), time_format) - datetime.strptime(in_time, time_format)
                    in_time = converTime(k["date"])
                    total_hours += dif
                    man_out = False
                    sessions.append(convert(dif.seconds))

            if k["punch"].__eq__(0):
                if not man_out:
                    man_in = False
                    man_out = True
                    if in_time != "null":
                        dif1 = (datetime.strptime(converTime(k["date"]), time_format) - datetime.strptime(in_time, time_format))
                        total_hours += dif1
                        sessions.append(convert(dif1.seconds))
        return is_present, total_hours.time().__str__(), sessions
    else:
        return is_present


def convert(seconds):
    seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
    hour = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60

    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)


t = calculate(shift, user_attendence, "22-04-2022", 1)
print(t)
```

output: (True, '05:00:10', ['1:00:00', '1:00:00', '1:00:00', '2:00:10'])

Comment: Where does the `user_attendance` list actually come from? Is this a placeholder literal for what will eventually be some kind of user interface, or does the user interface exist already? Is it retrieved from a file?

Comment: For the sample input data you've provided, your code does not output what you've shown.

Comment: user_attendace will be retrieved form file.

Answer (score 1):

There's no evidence that your dates and datetimes should ever be represented as strings. Use real `date`, `datetime` and `timedelta`; and don't call into `strptime` or `strftime`.

`getDays`, `set_timeformat`, `convert` and `converTime` can all go away.

`user_attendance` should not be a global, and its members should have at least a simple object representation instead of being untyped dictionaries. `NamedTuple` is well-suited.

`time_format` can go away.

`shift` should be a tuple instead of a list for immutability, should be datetimes instead of strings, and should not be global.

`set_timeformat` seems like it was meant to be a class method due to `self`, but it isn't - so including `self` makes no sense.

Add PEP484 type hints.

`shift1` should at least be a tuple of two datetimes that gets unpacked to a shift start and shift end variable; but more likely it should just be accepted as two separate parameters.

Rather than

```
shift1[0] <= i["date"] <= shift1[1]
```

which is a closed interval, consider instead a half-open interval:

```
shift1[0] <= i["date"] < shift1[1]
```

This has more useful properties when it comes to algorithmic design, and is usually what the Python built-ins do.

Don't `i.get("punch").__eq__(1)`; just `i.punch`, which itself should be represented as a boolean.

You should probably return the same number of arguments regardless of whether `is_present` is `True` or not. But beyond that: why not just unconditionally return `total_hours` (which should be a `timedelta`) and `sessions`, which will be zero and empty if `is_present` is `False`?

### Suggested

This still needs improvement, but is a start covering some of the above:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint
from typing import NamedTuple, Sequence


class UserAttendance(NamedTuple):
    id: int
    punch: bool
    date: datetime


def calculate(
    shift1: tuple[datetime, datetime],
    user_attendence: Sequence[UserAttendance],
    id: int,
) -> tuple[
    timedelta,        # total hours present
    list[timedelta],  # session durations
]:
    man_in = False
    man_out = False
    sessions = []
    total_hours = timedelta()
    in_time = None

    shift_start, shift_end = shift1

    attendance = [
        i for i in user_attendence
        if shift_start <= i.date < shift_end
        and i.id == id
    ]
    is_present = any(i.punch for i in attendance)

    if is_present:
        for k in attendance:
            if k.punch:
                if man_in:
                    dif = k.date - in_time
                    in_time = k.date
                    total_hours += dif
                    man_out = False
                    sessions.append(dif)
                else:
                    in_time = k.date
                    man_in = True
                    man_out = False
            elif not man_out:
                man_in = False
                man_out = True
                if in_time is not None:
                    dif1 = k.date - in_time
                    total_hours += dif1
                    sessions.append(dif1)
    return total_hours, sessions


def main() -> None:
    user_attendence = [
        UserAttendance(**kwargs)
        for kwargs in (
            {"id": 1, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 2, 10, 0)},
            {"id": 1, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 3, 0,  0)},

            {"id": 1, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 4, 0,  0)},
            {"id": 1, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 5, 0,  0)},

            {"id": 1, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 6, 0,  0)},
            {"id": 1, "punch": False, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 8, 0, 10)},

            {"id": 2, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 4, 0,  0)},
            {"id": 2, "punch":  True, "date": datetime(2022, 4, 22, 5, 0,  0)},
        )
    ]

    shift = (
        datetime(2022, 4, 22, 2, 0, 0),
        datetime(2022, 4, 22, 9, 0, 0),
    )
    total_hours, sessions = calculate(shift, user_attendence, id=1)
    print(total_hours)
    pprint(sessions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
5:50:10
[datetime.timedelta(seconds=3000),
 datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
 datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
 datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600),
 datetime.timedelta(seconds=7210)]
```